# UIWebView goBack method acts differently on different devices

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, shouldstartload

First Device:

- 8gb 2nd gen
- Version: 3.1.3 (7E18)
- Model: MB528LL

Second Device:

- 32gb 3rd gen
- Version: 3.1.3 (7E18)
- Model: MC008LL

When I call goBack on the 8gb device, shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: is called

When I call goBack on the 32gb device, shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: is not called

I am not doing any caching (not like it works anyway). To make sure it wasn't caching I removed any possible caching via the request object's cache policy and removing all cache whenever webViewDidFinishLoading is called.

Same app, same url, everything is the same but the device itself.

Anyone know why this is would happen?

FYI: shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: is called on the simulator when goBack is called